# "pub serve test" throws error when requesting page

Tags: dart

Trying to run `pub serve test` with my dart project gives me the following message:

```
Loading source assets...
Loading dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers...
Serving mud test on http://localhost:8080
Build completed successfully
```

However, when I load `http://localhost:8080`, I get the following message:

```
[test] GET  → Could not find asset mud|test.
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── README.md
├── analysis_options.yaml
├── build
│   └── ...
├── lib
│   └── ...
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
├── test
│   ├── browser_test.dart
│   ├── browser_test.html
│   └── encounter_test.dart
└── web
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── index.html
    ├── main.dart
    └── styles.css
```

Comment: Could be https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32561#event-1529398183

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing `http://localhost:8080/browser_test.html' ?

`pub serve` does do listing when a directory is listed. Unless `index.html` exists, you should just get a 404.